# how to unblock a blocked socket?

Tags: python, sockets, blocking

Synopsis:
My program occasionally runs into a condition where it wants to send data over a socket, but that socket is blocked waiting for a response to a previous command that never came.  Is there any way to unblock the socket and pick back up with it when this happens?  If not that, how could I test whether the socket is blocked so I could close it and open a new one?  (I need blocking sockets in the first place)

Details:
I'm connecting to a server over two sockets.  Socket 1 is for general command communication.  Socket 2 is for aborting running commands.  Aborts can come at any time and frequently.  Every command sent over socket 1 gets a response, such as:

```
socket1 send: set command data
socket1 read: set command ack
```

There is always some time between the send and the read, as the server doesn't send anything back until the command is finished executing.

To interrupt commands in progress, I connect over a another socket and issue an abort command.  I then use socket 1 to issue a new command.

I am finding that occasionally commands issued over socket 1 after an abort are hanging the program.  It appears that socket 1 is blocked waiting for a response to a previously issued command that never returned (and that got interrupted).  While usually it works sometimes it doesn't (I didn't write the server).

In these cases, is there any way for me to check to see if socket 1 is blocked waiting for a read, and if so, abandon that read and move on?  Or even any way to check at all so I can close that socket and start again?

thx!

UPDATE 1: thanks for the answers.  As for why I'm using blocking sockets, it's because I'm controlling a CNC-type machine with this code, and I need to know when the command I've asked it to execute is done executing.  The server returns the ACK when it's done, so that seems like a good way to handle it.  I like the idea of refactoring for non-blocking but can't envision a way to get info on when the command is done otherwise.  I'll look at select and the other options.

Comment: i should have mentioned i've tried flushing the socket, and that i'm using the socket with a file descriptor (via makefd()).

Comment: I like Martin and Karl's answers. Another possibility is to use `socket.settimeout`, which causes socket operations to block, but only for a while.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure I quite understand the question. You say your socket is "blocked". Is that because another thread is actually currently blocked in a `recv` call on that socket? In other words: you have multiple threads trying to use the socket at once? If not, why do you think the socket is blocked? I'm a little confused because I don't normally think of the word "blocked" as applying to sockets. They have either blocking or non-blocking behavior, sure, but it's the thread that actually gets blocked. (Otherwise, this is a well-asked question, fwiw.)

Comment: it appears that the socket is hung waiting to read a response that never comes from the server (one it should have sent).  perhaps I'm describing it incorrectly.  i have a socket, and i send commands to it.  i've setup a writeread method that writes a command and waits for a response.  it looks like the socket thread hangs after the write but before the read.

Comment: oh, and i did try settimeout.  it does force the program to recover, but i can't really set a usable timeout because the command execution time is quite variable.  could be .5 second, or could be 20 seconds.  and i can't wait 20 seconds for it to recover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not meaning to seem disagreeable, but you say you need blocking sockets and then go on to describe some very good reasons for needing non-blocking sockets.  I would recommend refactoring to use non-blocking.

Aside from that, the only method I'm aware of to know if a socket is blocked is the fact that your program called `recv` or one of its variants and has not yet returned.  Someone else may know an API that I don't, but setting a "blocked" boolean before the `recv` call and clearing it afterward is probably the best hack to get you that info.  But you don't want to do that.  Trust me, the refactor will be worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional solution to this problem is to use [select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html). Before writing, test whether the socket will support writing, and if not, do something else (such as waiting for a response first). One level above select, Python provides the [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html) module to enable such processing. Two level above, [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is an entire framework dealing with asynchronous processing of messages.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets should be full duplex. If Python blocks a thread from writing to a socket while another thread is reading from the same socket I would regard it as a major bug in Python. This doesn't occur in any other programming language I've used.

Answer (score 0):

What you really what is to block on a select() or poll().  The only way to unblock a blocked socket is to receive data or a signal which is probably not acceptable.  A select() or poll() call can block waiting for one or more sockets, either on reading or writing (waiting for buffer space).  They can also take a timeout if you want to wait periodically to check on other things.  Take a look at my answer to [Block Socket with Unix and C/C++ Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494052/block-socket-with-unix-and-c-c-help/5494556#5494556)